# jQuery mobile button group: How to center the complete vertical group?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I try currently to beautify my sources a little bit. For this I want to change the width of buttons and radio buttons to 80% and change the alignment to center. For the buttons I made css settings that works quite fine, but I am not able to center the radio button group.

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="testPage" data-theme="e">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend id="SettingsDifficulty"></legend>
        <input class="rbgroup1" type="radio" name="test" id="radio-choice-1" value="3" />
        <label for="radio-choice-1" id="label1" class="activeOnce">Radio 1</label>
        <input class="rbgroup1" type="radio" name="test" id="radio-choice-2" value="4" />
        <label for="radio-choice-2" id="label2" class="activeOnce">Radio 2</label>
        <input class="rbgroup1" type="radio" name="test" id="radio-choice-3" value="5" />
        <label for="radio-choice-3" id="label3" class="activeOnce">Radio 3</label>
    </fieldset>
    </br>
    <hr>
    </br>
<a href="#settings" data-role="button" id="buton" class="activeOnce">Button</a>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-btn.activeOnce
{
  width:80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

The single button at the end is now at 80% width and perfect centered. The radio buttons are also at 80% width but still left aligned. At the web I found some solutions for horizontal radio button groups, but this solutions does not work with data-type="vertical". Is there a way to center this, too?

Thank you very much for helping me :-).

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/7eKZb

Comment: you can use grids http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/BDHzz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery Mobile grid system, `ui-grid-b` and 3 blocks `ui-block-a`, `ui-block-b` and `ui-block-c`.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/BDHzz/)**

```html
<div class="ui-grid-b">
  <div class="ui-block-left ui-block-a"><!-- Placeholder --></div>
    <div class="ui-block-center ui-block-b">
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <!-- Buttons go here -->
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  <div class="ui-block-right ui-block-c"><!-- Placeholder --></div>
</div>
```

And override width of blocks a, b and c. I used extra custom classes in order not to override other blocks.

```
.ui-block-left, .ui-block-right {
  width: 10% !important;
}

.ui-block-center {
  width: 80% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bB2vM/

i wrapped your radio button group in a div and it worked see the fiddle

```
<div data-role="page" id="testPage" data-theme="e">
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <legend id="SettingsDifficulty"></legend>
    <div id="centregroup">
    <input class="rbgroup1" type="radio" name="test" id="radio-choice-1" value="3" />
    <label for="radio-choice-1" id="label1" class="activeOnce">Radio 1</label>
    <input class="rbgroup1" type="radio" name="test" id="radio-choice-2" value="4" />
    <label for="radio-choice-2" id="label2" class="activeOnce">Radio 2</label>
    <input class="rbgroup1" type="radio" name="test" id="radio-choice-3" value="5" />
    <label for="radio-choice-3" id="label3" class="activeOnce">Radio 3</label>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</br>
<hr>
</br>
```

Button

and here is the css

```
.ui-btn.activeOnce
{
  width:80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#centregroup
{
  text-align:center;    
}
```

See screeshot.

[image: In firefox]

Comment: No changes at my side, still left aligned but now without round corners.

Comment: which browser, are you using i can see it center-aligned in both Firefox and Internet explorer, only in Internet explorer the feildset is round at corners

Comment: I use FF. Hmm, seldom that it works on your side and not at my one.

Comment: Added a screenshot in the answer

Comment: With your changes it is like this : http://jsfiddle.net/7eKZb/1/ . Still left aligned.

Comment: Same with your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bB2vM/1/ . Thanks again for helping :-).

Answer (score 1):

U can group your radio buttons inside a div with fixed width and height:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical" style="text-align: center">
  <div class="centerRadio">
   <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" checked="checked" />
   <label for="radio-choice-1">A</label>
   <input data-theme="e" type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2"  />
   <label for="radio-choice-2">B</label>
 </div>
</fieldset>
```

CSS:

```
.centerRadio
{
width: 80%; margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ds345/jMJ57/4/)